# Is new cryptocurrency that runs only in raspberry pi possible?

Tags: currencies, raspberry-pi

Is it possible to create a cryptocurrency software that can run efficiently on a raspberryPi and has a mechanism to detect (based on maximum coin production?) if a node is using a better computer so the swarm rejects it's coins?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an altcoin that is only feasible to mine by CPU?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/17429/is-there-an-altcoin-that-is-only-feasible-to-mine-by-cpu)

Comment: @GregHewgill: Not a duplicate.  This question wants a mining algorithm that not only can only run on a CPU, but only on the CPU of a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: How would you be able to tell the difference between a thousand people with their own Raspberry Pis and one person with a very fast computer? You can solve a block with a different address every time, so there's not really a way to know.

Answer (score 2):

It possible to inject hardware detecting code into code of your mining software, but to protect the mechanism you cannot publish it as an open-source. That will make your currency not so popular as others. Even if you will be succesful there are people that will change the Raspberry Pi CPU and pass-by your mechanism.